# Convert csv file to table format pdf in Action Mailer(Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, actionmailer, pdfkit

I have a CSV file and I am converting it to pdf using `PDFkit` but the pdf is not formatted.

`I am sending both file CSV and pdf as an attachment.`

It simply comma-separated values in a cluttered format.

`Code`

```
inventory_csv = File.open(csv_file).read.lines.to_a.join
kit = PDFKit.new(inventory_csv,page_size: 'A4',
                 :orientation => 'Landscape',
                 :margin_top => '0in',
                 :margin_right => '0in',
                 :margin_bottom => '0in',
                 :margin_left => '0in')
kit.stylesheets << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/stylesheets/pdf/finance_report.css"
pdf = kit.to_pdf
```

and this gives me pdf like this
[image]

I wonder how this website is doing actually converting my CSV to well table format. How can I achieve that in my `Action mailer` code?

> https://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-pdf.htm

Below pdf screenshot has been generated by the above website

[image]

How can I achieve that programmatically using PDFkit?

Answer (score 0):

```
lines = File.open(csv_file).read.lines.to_a.join

table = ActionController::Base.helpers.content_tag :table, class: "table" do
    lines.map do |line|
      ActionController::Base.helpers.content_tag :tr do 
        line.split(",").map{|cell| ActionController::Base.helpers.content_tag :td, cell}.join.html_safe
      end
    end.join.html_safe
end

kit = PDFKit.new(table, page_size: 'A4',
             :orientation => 'Landscape',
             :margin_top => '0in',
             :margin_right => '0in',
             :margin_bottom => '0in',
             :margin_left => '0in')
kit.stylesheets << "#{Rails.root}/public/stylesheets/pdf/style.css"
pdf = kit.to_pdf
```